# ORA-22813: operand value exceeds system limits

Tags: oracle, object, plsql, oracle9i

I'm having an issue with an oracle object I created. The goal of the stored procedure is to either retreive all wires contained on an airplane or compare the list of wires with another one (past airplane wire configuration). You will understand that this can be quite big... I did a first shot with a table of objects. I make a select statement and loop through a cursor to insert values in my objects. The problem comes from when I try this:

```
OPEN P_CURSOR FOR
  SELECT * FROM TABLE(CAST(GET_WIRES(P_ACTUAL_HAR_LIST, P_END_IDENT_TYPES) AS TBL_TP_WIRE_LIST));
```

I get the ORA-22813: operand value exceeds system limits. So, I started looking on the internet and I found that I should have used a PIPELINED function, which I tryied. But, the PIPELINED function is not allowed in a PL/SQL context, so that doesn't fit my problem, since I need to rework the object afterward. So, I tryied a Global Temporary Table and I have now performance issue. I also tryied to contact the DBA if he could increase the PGA size, which he did (it's now 150mb) but I have the same problem. Maybe it's still not big enough, but I don't want him to reincrease it if it's not going to work... Just so you have an idea, I have 1 487 761 of those:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE TP_WIRE_LIST_ENTRY AS OBJECT (
  ATA_NUM                   VARCHAR2(8 BYTE),
  EFFECTIVITIES             VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  WIRE_ID                   VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  DRAWING_NO                VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  END_IDENT_1               VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  END_IDENT_2               VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  PIN_1                     VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  PIN_2                     VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  TERM_1                    VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  TERM_2                    VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  DES_LENGTH                NUMBER(6,2),
  TECH_PUBS_REMARKS         VARCHAR2(500 BYTE),
  WIRE_CODE                 VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  W_CODE                    VARCHAR2(3 BYTE),
  AWG                       VARCHAR2(3 BYTE),
  COLOR                     VARCHAR2(4 BYTE),
  GA                        VARCHAR2(6 BYTE),
  END_IDENT_DESC_1          VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  END_IDENT_DESC_2          VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  TECH_PUBS_REMARKS_1       VARCHAR2(500 BYTE),
  TECH_PUBS_REMARKS_2       VARCHAR2(500 BYTE),
  IDENT_TYPE_ID_1           VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  IDENT_TYPE_ID_2           VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  BUS_NAME_1                VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  PROPERTY_COLLECTION_ID_1  NUMBER(10,0),
  BUS_NAME_2                VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  PROPERTY_COLLECTION_ID_2  NUMBER(10,0),
  X_1                       NUMBER(8,3),
  Y_1                       NUMBER(8,3),
  Z_1                       NUMBER(8,3),
  UOM_1                     VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  X_2                       NUMBER(8,3),
  Y_2                       NUMBER(8,3),
  Z_2                       NUMBER(8,3),
  UOM_2                     VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  COORD_CODE_1              VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  COORD_CODE_2              VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  UOM_DESC_1                VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  UOM_DESC_2                VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  PART_NO                   VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  PART_DESC                 VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  WIRE_GAUGE                VARCHAR2(4 BYTE),
  SPEC_REFERENCE            VARCHAR2(60 BYTE),
  MPS_NUM                   VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  PPS_NUM                   VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  INSERTION_TOOL            VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
  EXTRACTION_TOOL           VARCHAR2(25 BYTE) 
);
/
```

We work with Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.6.0

Best regards,

Comment: It's not clear why you're using a collection at all.  That data's got to come from somewhere, right?  So where does it come from?  Also, what do you mean by "But, the PIPELINED function is not allowed in a PL/SQL context, so that doesn't fit my problem"?

Comment: Why do you still work with 9i which is 8 years out of date?

Comment: Is it possible to build GET_WIRES as a view rather than a procedure ?

Comment: APC - Data come from a Select statement with multiple joins. I need the object to create kind of a new table. The first table of the select statement is another object, that is dynamically created depending on, for example, the aircraft program, the report type, etc. Kevin - No because the main table of the statement is dynamic (another object) Tony - That comment is unappropriated. The reason why we still use 9i is because our client does so, that's all! Ask them why they don't pay for a new version of Oracle!

Comment: Kevin - no because to retrieve the wires, we must have a list of identificator that is dynamic depending on the context

Comment: Just some math: 150 MB with 1 487 761 objects makes only `150*1024*1024 bytes / 1487761 objects = 105 bytes/object`. Clearly a single `TP_WIRE_LIST_ENTRY` object takes much more than that.

Comment: That is an interresting point, but I had the DBA changed the PGA to 1GO so that it fits the PROD environment (DEV was smaller) I'll keep you informed if that worked!!!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar situation in a data warehousing environment at a past job.

Did your DBA increate pga_aggregate_target or _pga_max_size or both?  Keep in mind that when the DBA increases pga_aggregate_target to 150MB that doesn't mean that your session would be able to grab all of that 150MB.  Oracle will only allow a given session to take a small fraction of that space.  Increasing pga_aggregate_target from 150MB to 200MB will only give your session a few extra megs of memory to play with for in-memory operations IIRC.

If your DB server has more available memory, you'll have to have your DBA increase both pga_aggregate_target and _pga_max_size, otherwise you'll have to look at using a GTT or creating a scratch table to dump your data into and then work on it from there.

Comment: Thank for that answer! I Will ask him... I Also asked him to increase the PGA to 1GO and I cleaned half of the columns of the objects... I'll post an answer if that fits...

Comment: How large is the data set you're working on?  Do you need to pull the EFFECTIVITIES column in?  If your average column size there is anything close 4K that's a huge result set you need to manage in memory.  If it's too large for the size of your environment you may still have to dump it to a GTT or permanent table you can put some indexes on.  Has your DBA pulled

Comment: @Fragmatyc a max pga size of 1GB isn't that large. As I work it out the max column length is 6,387, i.e. if you use 50% of this you're looking at 4.25Gb of memory you personally need. As a minimum. It should be about 10Gb to be safe. Kabar is correct; you're going to need to create a normal table to dump your data into. If you always put your data into this type then you can loop through your cursor and put it straight into the type without bothering with the object.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add this tidbit in case it helps someone else.  We suddenly started getting this error in our PL/SQL when the DBA set RESULT_CACHE_MODE to AUTO as a test for another process.  We didnt know he did this until much later.  Anyway, setting it back to MANUAL fixed this problem.