# Combine multiple clob rows into one

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table which has 2 fields :

1) **id** - number

2) **description** - clob

This table has multiple rows for one particular id. I want to create one other table using this table which combine the `clob` rows into one for a particular id. I am trying to use below sql to combine the rows -

```
    SELECT id,
        rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e,
                description,
               CHR (10) || CHR (10) ).extract('//text()')
 order by rowid).GetClobVal(),chr(10)||chr(10))
               description2
       FROM table a
   GROUP BY id
```

But this is giving me `ORA-22813` error. Is there any workaround to solve this?

> ORA-22813: operand value exceeds system limits

Comment: Have you seen: [ORA-22813: operand value exceeds system limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597053/ora-22813-operand-value-exceeds-system-limits) ? Looks to me like your `CLOB`s are large and combining them creates a **huge** XML document.

Comment: Yes CLOB string is 29k characters long

Answer (score 0):

Here description and Action for the error is:

> **ORA-22813**: Operand value exceeds system limits.
>
> **Cause**:  Object or Collection value was too large. The size of the value might have exceeded 30k in a SORT context, or the size might be
>   too big for available memory.
>
> **Action**:  Choose another value and retry the operation.

BUT, We can skip those records which, after concatenation going to be larger than 30K. Means We can show "ERROR IN CONCATENATION" instead of actual concatenation as it is anyway not possible.

Try following. It should work for you.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    CASE
        WHEN SUM((DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH("DESCRIPTION"))) / 1024 < 30 
        THEN 
        RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, DESCRIPTION, CHR(10)
        || CHR(10)).EXTRACT('//text()')  ORDER BY
                ROWID
        ).GETCLOBVAL(), CHR(10)
                        || CHR(10))
        ELSE TO_CLOB('ERROR IN CONCATENATION')
    END AS DESCRIPTION2
FROM
    TABLEA
GROUP BY
    ID;
```

This is a limited functionality workaround.

Posted the answer considering that it may be useful to you.

Cheers!!